# call ajax from another file error at url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="layout" content="main" />
    <title>aaaaa</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#a").change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        data: $("#awardType").val(),
                    },
                    url: '${createLink(controller:' a ', action:' b ')}',
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        showAjaxLoading();
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#a').html(result);
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        hideAjaxLoading();
                    },
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

when i working on this and take this script inside this file ... everything work fine . but i take this script to another file and call that file ... it is not working ...

i have file a.js and take script inside this file

and call it inside the html file

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="layout" content="main" />
    <style type="text/css">
</style>
    <title>
        <g:message code="awards.title" default="Awards" />
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir: 'js', file: 'a.js') }"></script>
</head>
```

now it is not working ....

Comment: By including a javascript file it will not be loaded on document.ready

Comment: Take care of the last line in the ajax call  `},` - it can cause problems in some versions of IE.

Comment: If you go to the browser developer tools, e.g. shift-control-J in chrome, does all the code of this ajax script show up in the sources that were loaded? You should be able to see that whole script somewhere, not just the script tag line.

Comment: Whatever you have behind `url` does not make any sense and should create a SyntaxError.

Comment: Also, what are the exact browser console errors?

Comment: @Sumurai8 The `src` attribute in the `script` line seems invalid unless it is preprocessed by something.  Is that what you mean by `url`?

Comment: As `type="text/javascript"` isn't really needed any more, then usually a `script` tag looks like this `<script src="/js/a.js"></script>` . The path might have to be adjusted, but the keywords "resource", "dir", and "file" are not HTML and suggest either an error or some kind of preprocessing/framework.

Comment: Why dont you add it the normal way like `<script src"a.js"></script><script src"b.js"></script>` and so on??

Comment: because i'm using grails .grails have folder js . if i import some file not using ajax . everthing ok . but when i using ajax the error at url .

Comment: i wrote plugin js , and included it . now everything ok .... thanks everybody